# How can I add a custom attribute to a popup_menu using CGI.pm?

Tags: perl, cgi

I use the following Perl code to generate an HTML popup menu with `CGI.pm`:

```
$html->popup_menu(
    -name     => "to",
    -values   => [@TO, $param_to],
    -labels   => {%TO, $param_to => $param_to,},
    -default  => $param_to,
    -onchange => $onchange,
    -class    => "form-control"
);
```

The generated menu looks like this:

```html
<select name="to" onchange="if (this.value=='support@abc.com' || document.theForm.supportform.value==1) document.theForm.submit();" class="form-control">
<option value=""> select recipient </option>
<option value="sales@abc.com">Sales Inquiry</option>
<option value="support@abc.com">Technical Support</option>
<option value="jobs@abc.com">Jobs @ abc</option>
<option value="investor-relations@abc.com">Investor Relations</option>
<option value="webmaster@abc.com">abc Webmaster</option>
</select>
```

How can I add the attribute `required` to the `<select>` element?

Comment: Please don't use the HTML generation methods in CGI.pm They were never a good idea and [they are about to be deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used).

Comment: Dave thanks for the great advice, I had no idea. I will make sure to not make calls to CGI.pm. Trying to figure out a good alternative to the same. LMK if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Use a templating system. See [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).

Answer (score 1):

According to the `CGI` documentation:

> Many routines will do something useful with a named argument that it doesn't recognize.

So just add another named argument `-required`:

```
$html->popup_menu(
    -name     => "to",
    -values   => [@TO, $param_to],
    -labels   => {%TO, $param_to => $param_to,},
    -default  => $param_to,
    -onchange => $onchange,
    -class    => "form-control",
    -required => "required"
);
```

This will generate something like:

```html
<select name="to" ... required="required">
```

However, generating HTML with `CGI.pm` is a pain and not very maintainable. It's better to use a templating library like [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/). Templates allow you to separate your Perl code and your HTML (mostly), so you can have something like this:

*popup.tt*

```
<select name="to" onchange="if (this.value=='support@abc.com' || document.theForm.supportform.value==1) document.theForm.submit();" class="form-control">
  [% FOR option IN options %]
  <option value="[% option.value %]">[% option.text %]</option>
  [% END %]
</select>
```

*my_script.cgi*

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new or die Template->error;

my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header;

my $options = [
    { value => '', text => 'select recipient' },
    { value => 'sales@abc.com', text => 'Sales Inquiry' },
    { value => 'support@abc.com', text => 'Technical Support' },
    { value => 'jobs@abc.com', text => 'Jobs @ abc' },
    { value => 'investor-relations@abc.com', text => 'Investor Relations' },
    { value => 'webmaster@abc.com', text => 'abc Webmaster' }
];

$tt->process('foo.tt', { options => $options }) or die $tt->error;
```

*Output*

```html
<select name="to" onchange="if (this.value=='support@abc.com' || document.theForm.supportform.value==1) document.theForm.submit();" class="form-control">

  <option value="">select recipient</option>

  <option value="sales@abc.com">Sales Inquiry</option>

  <option value="support@abc.com">Technical Support</option>

  <option value="jobs@abc.com">Jobs @ abc</option>

  <option value="investor-relations@abc.com">Investor Relations</option>

  <option value="webmaster@abc.com">abc Webmaster</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my code base is huge. And it will take me forever to implement the template system. I may be wrong feel free to lmk if I am making wrong assumption. I have close to 40 pages website, with 10 full blown applications. For now am going just spit out the html element instead of using cgi.pm in built functions.